# Why cant I get the value of the label?

Tags: jquery

im trying to get the value of the selected label, and when it changes get the value of the selected label, I have a configurable product and when someone selects either option the price changes see below:

[image]

the difference in price is +/- £2.40 depending on what option is selected, I have a dynamic price when someone changes the quantity it calculates the price taking in what option has been selected, but I'm having trouble getting the value of the selected option as it shows me a blank field.

[image]

```
        <div class="input-box">
       <select name="super_attribute[183]" id="attribute183" class="required-entry super-attribute-select" style="left: -10000px; position: absolute;">
          <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
          <option value="90" price="2.4">With Screws +£2.40</option>
          <option value="89" price="0">Without Screws</option>
       </select>
       <div class="switcher-field switcher-screws" id="attribute183_switchers">
           <label class="switcher-label" id="attribute183_90" value="90" title="With Scews" style="width:60px;height:60px;line-height:60px">
           <img src="image" alt="With Scews">
           </label>
           <label class="switcher-label selected" id="attribute183_89" value="89" title="Without Screws -£2.40" style="width:60px;height:60px;line-height:60px">
           <img src="image2" alt="Without Screws -£2.40">
           </label>
           <div style="clear:both"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Im using the current jQuery code

```
var selectedOption = jQuery('.switcher-screws label.selected');
selectedOption.on('change', function(){
    var optionvalue = $(this).val()
})
console.log(optionvalue);
```

I've tried

```
var selectedOption = jQuery('.switcher-screws label.selected');
optionvalue = selectedOption.val()
console.log(optionvalue);
```

but it just gives me a blank value, any ideas on where I'm going wrong ?

EDIT: I managed to get the value of the label by using on click

```
    jQuery('label.switcher-label').click( function(){

            var sellabel = jQuery('label.switcher-label.selected').attr('value');

            console.log(sellabel);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. When called on an empty
>   collection, it returns undefined.

It won't return the value of the label, you can try using the `attr` function:

```
var selectedOption = jQuery('.switcher-screws label.selected');
optionvalue = selectedOption.attr('value');
```

Comment: could I do an on('change') function with this ?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, the on method binds a callback for the change event, so anything could be done within its callback function

Comment: would you bind the selectedOption.on('change', function(){
    var optionvalue = $(this).attr('value');

   });

Comment: @MrJoshFisher You can't use the `onchange` event on static elements, that do not change. Please elaborate, which problem you are trying to solve. What you are doing here so far away from any standard (not using valid HTML; inventing events on elements, where they don't make sense…) that I do wonder, where you got this from.

Comment: Ok in a div with a class 'switcher-screws' is to label elements, and when you select either label the class 'selected' is added i want to get the value of the label with the class selected, make sense ? see edit

Answer (score 0):

A `<label>` does not have an attribute `value`. This is **invalid HTML**. Maybe that is why this does not work as you expected. Try to **use `data-*` attributes** to store the values:

```
<label
    class="switcher-label selected"
    id="attribute183_90"
    data-value="90"
    title="With Scews">
        <img src="imagewithoutscrews" alt="With Screws">
</label>
```

Retrieving the value in JS:

```
var value = jQuery('.switcher-label.selected').data('value);
```

**Using `onchange` with `<label>`:** Please do also keep in mind, that an `onchange` does not have any effect on a label, since the label content usually does not change. This looks like you try to emulate form inputs in some weird way. I guess you should describe what are you trying to do.

Comment: I've got a dynamic price on the page which changes when someone puts a quantity in so its (qty * product price) but the initial price changes if they select a different option so the new calculation would be (price after option is selected * qty)

Answer (score 0):

> As per HTML 5 standards and W3C rules, you can not write extra
>   attributes in tags which are not for that tag. for write extra
>   attributes in tag you have to add prefix 'data-' for value in label
>   tag you need to write `data-value="90"` instead of `value="90"`
>   because value is **not valid for label tag** it is valid for input field.

For this

```
<label class="switcher-label" id="attribute183_89" data-value="89" title="Without Screws -£2.40" style="width:60px;height:60px;line-height:60px">
```

in your jQuery code you can fetch that data-value using data() method

```
var optionvalue = jQuery('.switcher-screws label.selected').data('value');
```